# 502 bad gateway: nginx & gunicorn

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I'm getting a 502 error, here's the nginx log:

```
2015/09/04 15:25:31 [error] 1563#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/90158/test/test.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 142.29.143.200, server: hackerspace.sd72.bc.ca, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/90158/test/test.sock:/", host: "hackerspace.sd72.bc.ca"
```

I'm new to nginx/gunicorn and need to know what I can do next to troubleshoot this problem.

`/home/90158/test/test.sock` exists.

here's my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hackerspace.sd72.bc.ca;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test.error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/90158/test/src;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/90158/test/test.sock;
    }
}
```

and here's my gunicorn conf file:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling test_project"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid 90158
setgid www-data
chdir /home/90158/test

exec bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/90158/test/test.sock src/test_project.wsgi:application
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next steps to troubleshoot:

- Is the file actually a socket?
- Is your gunicorn server actually listening to the socket?

Per `unix`(7), `ECONNREFUSED` can be returned by `connect`(2) if the socket is not a "listening socket" -- a clunky way of saying, "something is listening".  "This error can also occur if the target filename is not a socket."

Comment: Thank you.  How do I do these two things?

Comment: You may want to ask separate, specific, stand-alone questions for each thing you need help with.  Questions don't belong in comments, because they don't help future visitors.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include how to do what you suggested?